# ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset targetAreas does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, select-by-attribute, error-000732

My goal with this script is to create 9 PDFs and 9 sheets within an Excel workbook. The script utilizes select by location, attributes, and searchcursors to read data to Excel and iterate through user defined areas.

When I run the script with no user defined functions, I do not encounter this error (ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset targetAreas does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)). However, when I attempt to consolidate my script into neat functions, the script errors out.

The output should have 9 PDFs in the pdf directory and an Excel sheet with 9 worksheets. I get the desired output when I don't consolidate. However, when I'm iterating the areas in cursor3 (see code snippet below), the first iteration is successful, but the second iteration fails. So my resulting pdf directory only contains one PDF.

```
# Looping through feature classes
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(highRiskAreas, 'HRM')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('targetAreas', ['Name', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor3:
    for area in cursor3:
        n = 0
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Area {}'.format(area[0]))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('targetAreas', 
                        where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(area[0]))
        for fc, fields in fieldDict.items():
            n = featureSelector(fc, fields) + 1
        mapMaker(area[1], area[0])
        wb.save('{}.xls'.format(os.path.splitext(
                os.path.basename(studyArea))[0]))
```

I've read through other questions with the same error, but can't find anything that specifies my issue.

The full consolidated code is below...

```
import arcpy, os, shutil, xlwt, time
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# User Defined Functions
def featureSelector(feature, fields):
    '''
    determines amount of fields in searchcursor
    '''
    global n
    fcShort = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(feature))[0]
    ws.write(n, 0, fcShort, header)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature, fcShort)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'targetAreas')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'HRM', 
                                    selection_type='SUBSET_SELECTION')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcShort, fields) as cursor1:
        for i, row in enumerate(cursor1, n):
            ws.write(i + 1, 0, row[0], hraFont)
            try:
                ws.write(i + 1, 1, row[1], hraFont)
            except IndexError:
                pass
            n += 1
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'targetAreas')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'HRM', 
                                    selection_type='REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcShort, fields) as cursor2:
        for i, row in enumerate(cursor2, n):
            ws.write(i + 1, 0, row[0], NonHRAFont)
            try:
                ws.write(i + 1, 1, row[1], NonHRAFont)
            except IndexError:
                pass
            n += 1
    return n

def fieldCalc(path = arcpy.env.workspace):
    '''
    Calculates field values for each feature class
    '''
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    fieldDict = {}
    for fc in fcs:
        if 'ATM' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD']
        elif 'Laund' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD', 'COMPANY_NA']
        elif 'LI_Immin' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['address']
        elif 'Pawn' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['IN_SingleL', 'USER_Store']
        elif 'Grocery' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD', 'COMPANY_NA']
        elif 'Restau' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['IN_SingleL']
    return fieldDict

def mapMaker(shape, name):
    global pdfDirectory
    # Condition determining landscape or portrait map layout
    if ((shape.extent.XMax - shape.extent.XMin) > 
        (shape.extent.YMax - shape.extent.YMin)):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(landscapemxd)
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
        layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('targetAreas')

        # In order to zoom to the selected targetted area, we need to create a 
        # feature layer
        # However, we don't want it visible on the hard copy map
        # The template mxd has a set symbology and we want to see that
        layer.visible = False
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 
                                where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(name))
        df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, 
                    os.path.join(pdfDirectory, 'Area_{}'.format(name)))
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    else:
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(portraitmxd)
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
        layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('targetAreas')
        layer.visible = False
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 
                    where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(name))
        df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, os.path.join(pdfDirectory, 
                                    'Area_{}'.format(name)))
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

def Start():
    '''
    Calls other functions
    Settings for excel document
    '''
    # Excel Document and settings
    global ws, wb, hraFont, header, NonHRAFont, n, pdfDirectory, area
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    hraFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index red, bold on')
    header = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black, bold on')
    NonHRAFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black')
    #areaFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black, height 28')

    # Creating dictionary for environmental features and 
    # their required attributes
    fieldDict = fieldCalc()

    # Creating PDF directory
    pdfDirectory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pdfs')
    if os.path.exists(pdfDirectory):
        shutil.rmtree(pdfDirectory)
        time.sleep(1)
        os.mkdir(pdfDirectory)
    else:
        os.mkdir(pdfDirectory)

    # Looping through feature classes
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(highRiskAreas, 'HRM')
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('targetAreas', ['Name', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor3:
        for area in cursor3:
            n = 0
            ws = wb.add_sheet('Area {}'.format(area[0]))
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('targetAreas', 
                            where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(area[0]))
            for fc, fields in fieldDict.items():
                n = featureSelector(fc, fields) + 1
            mapMaker(area[1], area[0])
            wb.save('{}.xls'.format(os.path.splitext(
                    os.path.basename(studyArea))[0]))


# Setting Variables
arcpy.env.workspace = r"xxx"
portraitmxd = r"xxx"
landscapemxd = r"xxx"
studyArea = r"xxxx"
targetAreas = r"xxx"
highRiskAreas = r"xxxx"

# Initializing Script
Start()
```

Full unconsolidated script...

```
import arcpy, os, shutil, xlwt, time
# Setting Variables
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\environmentalFeatures"
portraitmxd = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\portrait.mxd"
landscapemxd = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\landscape.mxd"
studyArea = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\NicetownTioga_CanvassingArea.shp"
targetAreas = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\targetAreas.shp"
highRiskAreas = r"C:\Users\tuk36101\Desktop\canvasScript\highRiskArea.shp"
# Initialize time
start = time.time()

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# User Defined Functions
def featureSelector(feature, fields):
    '''
    determines amount of fields in searchcursor
    '''
    fcShort = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(feature))[0]
    global n
    ws.write(n, 0, fcShort, header)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature, fcShort)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'targetAreas')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'HRM', selection_type='SUBSET_SELECTION')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcShort, fields) as cursor:
        for i, row in enumerate(cursor, n):
            ws.write(i + 1, 0, row[0], hraFont)
            try:
                ws.write(i + 1, 1, row[1], hraFont)
            except IndexError:
                pass
            n += 1
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'targetAreas')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcShort, 'INTERSECT', 'HRM', selection_type='REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcShort, fields) as featCur:
        for i, row in enumerate(featCur, n):
            ws.write(i + 1, 0, row[0], NonHRAFont)
            try:
                ws.write(i + 1, 1, row[1], NonHRAFont)
            except IndexError:
                pass
            n += 1

    return n

def fieldCalc(path = arcpy.env.workspace):
    '''
    Calculates field values for each feature class
    '''
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    fieldDict = {}
    for fc in fcs:
        if 'ATM' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD']
        elif 'Laund' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD', 'COMPANY_NA']
        elif 'LI_Immin' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['address']
        elif 'Pawn' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['IN_SingleL', 'USER_Store']
        elif 'Grocery' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['PRIMARY_AD', 'COMPANY_NA']
        elif 'Restau' in fc:
            fieldDict[fc] = ['IN_SingleL']
    return fieldDict

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Excel Formatting
hraFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index red, bold on')
header = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black, bold on')
NonHRAFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black')
#areaFont = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black, height 28')

# Excel Document
wb = xlwt.Workbook()

# Global Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(highRiskAreas, 'HRM')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')

# Returning necessary fields for each feature class   
fieldDict = fieldCalc()

# Looping through feature classes
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('targetAreas', ['Name']) as areaCursor:
    for area in areaCursor:
        n = 0
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Area {}'.format(area[0]))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('targetAreas', where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(area[0]))
        for fc, fields in fieldDict.items():
            n = featureSelector(fc, fields) + 1
wb.save('Nicetown.xls')

# Map of Areas
# Final Process

# Housing the map pdfs
pdfDirectory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pdfs')
if os.path.exists(pdfDirectory):
    shutil.rmtree(pdfDirectory)
    time.sleep(1)
    os.mkdir(pdfDirectory)
else:
    os.mkdir(pdfDirectory)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('targetAreas', ['Name', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        # Condition determining landscape or portrait map layout
        if (row[1].extent.XMax - row[1].extent.XMin) > (row[1].extent.YMax - row[1].extent.YMin):
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(landscapemxd)
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
            layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('targetAreas')

            # In order to zoom to the selected targetted area, we need to create a feature layer
            # However, we don't want it visible on the hard copy map
            # The template mxd has a set symbology and we want to see that
            layer.visible = False
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(row[0]))
            df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, os.path.join(pdfDirectory, 'Area{}'.format(row[0])))
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        else:
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(portraitmxd)
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
            layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('targetAreas')
            layer.visible = False
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, where_clause="\"Name\" = '{}'".format(row[0]))
            df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r'pdfs\Area{}'.format(row[0]))
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

# End time
end = time.time()
total = ('{:.2f} minutes'.format((end-start)/60))
print total
```

Comment: Try creating `targetAreas` as a `Layer` object rather than just a string and passing it in to any function as a parameter that needs it. i.e. `target_areas_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas').getOutput(0)`

Comment: I applied this method to all instances of 'targetAreas', but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by bringing...

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(targetAreas, 'targetAreas')
```

into the for loop directly below it. My speculation is that the feature layer disappears when applied to the mapMaker function so a new feature layer needs to be created for each iteration.